# Partition array of size n into 2 subsets of size m such that difference between their sums is minimum

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dynamic

A set is given in form of an array (size n).
It is to be partitioned into two subsets of given size m.
The only constraint being that the difference between the sum of these subsets is minimum.

Comment: Have you tried a solution yet?

Comment: I know how to solve this without the subset size constraint.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/

Comment: What did i do wrong? Why downvotes?

Comment: Questions showing no effort are usually not receieved well.

Comment: This is an exercise. The strategies are explained. Example codes are provided. What exactly do you want from SO users, that this tutorial doesn't provide?

Comment: For me that tutorial is entirely different from this problem as here we need equal sized subsets and that too a fixed size. I just need a way to proceed. I am stuck here. That i want from my fellow SO users.

Comment: A few moments with a search engine reveals https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItF22I8f3Xs, among others. Google is your friend. Learn how to use it.

Comment: @JimMischel It seems you have wasted your "few moments" as that solution is far from correct. For starters the ques is different, secondly the video gives a WRONG solution for the ques he is trying to solve, let apart optimal.

Comment: If I was sure of that video, I would have posted an answer rather than a comment. My point is that this is a fairly well-known problem, the solution to which you can find much more easily by spending a few minutes searching rather than posting a question here and waiting ... 19 hours now ... for somebody to post the solution for you. That you haven't shown us any effort at all indicates that you don't understand the purpose of this site. We're not here to do your homework for you.